# Grouping Sets of Rows with a toggle.button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to hide groups of rows with a toggle button. In this instance, Rows 15 through 20, 22 through 25, 27 and finally 30 through 32.

The code I have so far works as intended.

```vb
Private Sub ToggleButton5_Click()
    Dim xAddress As String
    
    xAddress = ("15:20")
    If ToggleButton5.Value Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True
        ToggleButton5.Caption = "Show Assets"
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = False
        ToggleButton5.Caption = "Hide Assets"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

How do I add multiple groups to this row?

I tried

> xAddress = ("15:20,22:25")
>
> xAddress = "15:20,22:25"
>
> xAddress = ("15:20 And 22:25")

and I tried individually

> xAddress = ("15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25")

This last line works somewhat but runs into errors if more than maybe six row numbers are cited (going from memory on past attempts).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Range` instead of `Rows`.

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Range(xAddress).Hidden = True
```

If you are using `Range`, make sure that the row reference is in the form `row:row`, e.g. `1:1, 2:2, 3:3` and not `1, 2, 3`.

I generally steer clear of `Rows`. For example,

```
Debug.Print Rows("1,2,3").Address
```

returns

```
$123:$123
```

Not what you expect, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a "toggle", then consider the implementation of a "radio-button-logic". It is either **on** or **off**, thus if it is not `Hidden` it should be `Hidden` and vice versa. Usually it is 1 line only:

```
Sub ToggleRowsVisibility()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("15:20,22:25")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With

End Sub
```

In the case of the code, it can be outside the `If` condition:

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = ToggleButton5.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**
To hide/unhide a multiple selection *(i.e. non-contiguous or multiple areas)* of rows by the click of a button.

*Target rows:* [15:20], [22:25], [27] and [30:32]    *(row 27 included to show a mixed of rows combination).*

**Non VBA Solution:**
This can be achieved without VBA. Use the [Range.Group method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.group) manually to group the rows. Unfortunately, this method cannot be applied at once to a multiple selection, so you’ll have to apply the method to each range of contiguous rows separately.

1. Select the first range of rows to be `grouped` *(i.e. [15:20])*
2. In the Excel menu, click the [Data] tab then in the [Outline] group, click the [Group] option in the [Group] dropdown menu.
   [image]
3. The rows selected are now `grouped` with a button beside the rows heading. Use this button to toggle the visibility of the respective grouped rows.
   [image]
4. Repeat the action for the remaining group of rows.
   [image]

The advantages of this method compared with the VBA method are:

- *The grouped rows are fixed, even if new rows are added or deleted*. With the VBA method the rows are “hard-coded” and will lose focus when rows are inserted\deleted.
  [image]
- *The visibility of the Group of rows can be toggle all at once using the buttons located at the top\left angle, i.e. 1 to hide and 2 to unhide.*
  [image]
- *The visibility of the Group of rows can be toggle independently from each other using each group's button located in the rows heading.* Vba would required either independent buttons or additional variables.
  [image]

**VBA Solution:**
If you must use VBA then I suggest to use the correct syntax for multiple selection:

For a single row use:  `Rows(15).Select` or `Range("15:15").Select`
For a range of contiguous rows use:  `.Rows("15:20").Select` or `Range("15:20").Select`

For multiple selection of rows use the `Range` method as the `Rows` method doesn't work with multiple areas and when applied to a multiple selection returns only the rows of the first area.
For multiple selection of single rows use:  `.Range("30:30,32:32,34:34,36:36,39:39").Select`
For multiple selection of non-contiguous rows use:  `.Range("15:20,22:25,27:27").Select`

**Proposed VBA Solution:**
Following the above your code should be:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton5_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
    xAddress = "15:20,22:25,27:27,30:32"   'Update as required
    With ToggleButton1
        Me.Range(xAddress).Rows.Hidden = .Value
        .Caption = IIf(.Value, "Show Assets", "Hide Assets")
    End With
    End Sub
```